# How to add a Jmeter variable to JAVA variable in BeanShell Sampler?

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

**BeanShell Sampler**

```
int totalVerify = Integer.parseInt("${total}");
int totalBefVerify = Integer.parseInt("${totalBefVerify}");


totalVerify+${addTo};

if (totalVerify == totalBefVerify) {
return true;
}

return false;
```

**Result**

```
int totalVerify = Integer.parseInt("4100");
int totalBefVerify = Integer.parseInt("4104");

totalVerify+4;

if (totalVerify == totalBefVerify) {
return true;
}

return false;
```

Expected result is true, but for some reason Java variable is not adding to jmeter variable. Could you please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I made a mistake. See third line.

```
int totalVerify = Integer.parseInt("4100");
int totalBefVerify = Integer.parseInt("4104");

**totalVerify=**totalVerify+4;

if (totalVerify == totalBefVerify) {
return true;
}

return false;
```